# What are Microsoft Office Server Proofs and are they related to language packs?

Tags: 2010, office-integration, office, language-pack, service-pack-2

I was doing an analysis of my client's SharePoint 2010 server to view which language packs were installed.

I viewed the installed products and patches under 
`Central Administration -> Upgrade and Migration -> Check product and patch installation status` 
and only saw the English language pack listed.

I also checked the registry, just to be sure.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\InstalledLanguages\`

The `InstallLanguages` folder wasn't present, so I assumed the only language available was the language in which SharePoint 2010 was installed with (English).

From these findings, I would assume that no additional language packs were installed into this SharePoint 2010 server, *however*, I was confused when I saw  several "Microsoft Office Server Proof 2010" installations in different languages.

[image: Microsoft Proof Installs]

Are these related to language packs? I'm about to install SP2 for SharePoint 2010, and I need to know if I need to install various Language Pack SP2 updates.

*Version: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, on-premise*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are not related to the Language packs rather these are part of the Core SharePoint Installation. So no need to worry about Lanaguage Packs.

From the screen shot, i can confirm no language packs installed on that farm.

here are the default proofs tool which installed by default.

- Microsoft Office Server Proof (Spanish) 2010
- Microsoft Office Server Proof (Russian) 2010
- Microsoft Office Server Proof (French) 2010
- Microsoft Office Server Proof (Arabic) 2010
- Microsoft Office Server Proof (English) 2010
- Microsoft Office Server Proof (German) 2010